# About transformation of Variables

Tags: probability, distributions, density-function, integral

In a probability chapter of a Python Book, there is the following problem involving a transformation of variables:

[image: Z Function]

[image: First Step]

I don't fully understand where the value **1/z+1** in Y > X(**1/z+1**) comes from, and how you evaluate the integral in the interval max(X,X(1/z+1))< Y < 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality directly comes from substitution:
$$Z<z\rightarrow \frac{X}{Y-X}<z\rightarrow X(1+z)<zY\rightarrow Y>X(1/z+1)$$

Then, for the integral boundaries, we have two conditions: $Y>X$ and $ Y>X(1/z+1)$, which can be written as $Y>\max(X,X(1/z+1))$ more compactly. Also, since $z>0$ and $X\geq 0$, this maximum is equal to $X(1/z+1)$.

The explanation first integrates the double integral over $Y$ and then $X$. The inner integral was
$$\int_0^1 \{Y>\underbrace{X(1/z+1)}_\alpha\} dY=\int_\alpha^1 dY=1-\alpha=1-\frac{X}{z}-X=\frac{z-X-Xz}{z}$$

Comment: I see it now! Thank you very much!